# Android Spinner items space

Tags: android, xml, spinner

I have two spinners in my app. One spinner statically loads List items from XML file to display. Other spinner gets list of strings from database and displays. I am using same XML attributes for both spinners. But the spacing between individual items is different for both. The spinner with static list of strings has more spacing between items. The spinner which loads items from database has some sort of wrapped height. The items are close to each other making it difficult for user to select. 
Any solution for this problem?

```
  <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

**java code**

```
static_sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);        
    List<String> array_karant = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.karant_list));
    ArrayAdapter<String> karant_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_karant);
    karant_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    static_sp.setAdapter(karant_adapter);
    static_sp.setSelection(0);
    static_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new select_karant());


    database_sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);  
    return_likes = db.getAllLikeList();
    ArrayAdapter<String> like_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, return_likes);
             like_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    database_sp.setAdapter(like_adapter);
    database_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new select_like());
```

Link to image is here:

[image: https://img.photobucket.com/albums/v311/flowofthoughts/SPINNER_zpsd5a86cf1.png]

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: u have to create the custom spinner

Answer (score 0):

create a layout simple_spinner_item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and change your code

```
static_sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);        
List<String> array_karant = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.karant_list));
ArrayAdapter<String> karant_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_karant);
karant_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
static_sp.setAdapter(karant_adapter);
static_sp.setSelection(0);
static_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new select_karant());


database_sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);  
return_likes = db.getAllLikeList();
ArrayAdapter<String> like_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, return_likes);
         like_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
database_sp.setAdapter(like_adapter);
database_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new select_like());
```

If u want spacing u have to added the padding to the textview

Comment: the design of the drop down is the same as the design of the simple_spinner_item. so u can change ur design of the drop down u want.

Answer (score 0):

create a layout simple_spinner_item.xml, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
 android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
 android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
 android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
 android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>
```

The last two  lines is for add space between each item, then you have modify your class, in this line:

```
karant_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_karant);
```

Because you are using the android layout and we need use our layout (delete the word android.):

```
karant_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_karant);
```